# Can't find the database file

Tags: objective-c, ios

I can't figure why db.sqlite can't be found. I added it to the resource dir of the project. It is there. 
Here is some code how I check for existing.

```
-(void)getDatabaseLocation
{
    NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Build the path to the database file
   NSString *databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"db.sqlite"]];

   NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
     if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
     {
         NSLog(@"NO"); // It's say no when this method  is called.
     }
    else
    {   NSLog(@"YES");
    }
}
```

//EDIT
Now I check that the path in docsDir doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it isn't there. You must first copy the resource to the documents directory, like this:

```
if (![filemgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath])
{
    [filemgr copyItemAtPath:[NSBundle.mainBundle pathForResource:@"db" ofType:@"sqlite"] toPath:databasePath error:nil]; 
}
```

EDIT: If you only need to do lookups on the database (no editing), then you can simply do this:

```
databasePath = [NSBundle.mainBundle pathForResource:@"db" ofType:@"sqlite"];
```

Comment: He only needs to copy it to the docdir, if he wants to modify it. For lookups only it can simply remain in the resource dir.

Comment: I need the database only for SELECT statements

Comment: @Profo I edited my answer if you don't need a writable database.

Comment: I get expected identifier on line 
 [filemgr copyItemAtPath:[NSBundle.mainBundle pathForResource:@"db" ofType:@"sqlite"] toPath:databasePath error:nil];

Comment: @Profo I do not. Did you happen to remove the lines that declare your file manager / database location?

Comment: I think
[filemgr copyItemAtPath:[NSBundle.mainBundle pathForResource:@"db" ofType:@"sqlite"] toPath:databasePath error:nil];

should be 
[filemgr copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"db" ofType:@"sqlite"] toPath:databasePath error:nil]; 
correct ?

Comment: @Profo the dot syntax is optional, of course, I just find that it makes it easier to read.